# Copying dataframe column dict into Django JsonField

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a table created with Django(3+) on a postgres database (10+).

```
Class Cast(models.Models):
    profiles=JSONField(null=True)
```

I am trying to copy a dataframe with a column full of python dict of the form `{'test':'test'}`.

When I use the command: `df.to_sql('cast',engine,if_exists='append')` I get the following error:

> (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'dict'

I tried replacing my dict by `None` and it worked well.
I have correctly added `'django.contrib.postgres'` in `INSTALLED_APPS` ( I don't know if this  should be done before creating the database but I guess not)

I must add that the postgres database is on a remote server, the django code is on my local computer and the code to copy the dataframe on a second remote server.

Answer (score 1):

Applying a `json.dumps` to the column before the df.to_sql solved the issue